# Transitivity in javascript

Tags: javascript

In mathematics, = is assumed to be a transitive relationship. Transitivity means precisely what you stated: A = B and B = C implies A = C.But, from what I can see, javascript does not respect this transitivity principle.

For all of the below expressions, the output is TRUE

```
[]==0
true

0==[]
true

"0" == 0
true

0 == "0"
true
```

But, this is false

```
"0" == []
false
```

What is the reason behind it, and how compiler treat this expression?

Comment: in mathematics transitivity holds only when A, B, C are of the same type. In js examples not all items are of the same type

Comment: Maybe its doing coercion like this; `"0" == [].toString()`...

Comment: try `"" == []` instead

Comment: Correct, `==` is not transitive in JavaScript. Just don’t use it except in special cases; the `===` operator’s behaviour is much simpler. (And it is transitive. Not reflexive though.)

Comment: @NikosM. Programming often takes mathematics less strictly

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) documentation on the non-strict Javascript equality operator. It attempts to convert objects which do not have the same type, and while it apparently supports [] and 0, it does not have coercion for "0" and [].

My guess at the reasoning behind this: 0 is commonly used to represent the Boolean value of False. [] has a value of False when converted to Boolean, so it is expedient to say that `[] == 0` in Boolean terms. `"0" == 0`, however, is true for a different reason; the string "0" represents the integer 0. In logical terms, the equality operator is actually representing two different relations, so transitivity does not hold between them.

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand value is being coerced to a string.

```js
console.log("0" == []) // false
console.log([].toString()) // ""
console.log("" == [].toString()) // true
console.log("0" == [0].toString()) // true
console.log([0, 1, 2, 3].toString()) // 0,1,2,3
console.log("0,1,2,3" == [0, 1, 2, 3]) // true
```

Comment: What about `[]==0` then?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's aggressive type of coercion leads to odd results. The string equivalent of an empty array is an empty string, so that is why it works.
As well, converting an empty string to a number gives zero, so you can also convert Array to Number.
The string "0" is equal to 0 because calling 0.toString gives "0".
But we said earlier that an empty array becomes an empty string, so we can't have "0" as a converted version of an empty array.

All this happens in the first place due to "==", which coerces types. With "===", **none** of these equalities are true.